# The problem of (was)

Tags: descriptive-grammar

I used this sentence in a motivational letter, and I am worried if the usage of (was) in this sentence is right or wrong because I discovered the problem very late:

> I have been fascinated by the way electrical circuits function, and how companies make devices and machines with sophisticated electronic systems which was a sort of magic for me.

Note: I meant that the whole thing about electricity was a sort of magic for me.

Comment: <tl;dr>It's fine.</tl> An English speaker will search back from *which* to find the thing referred to, i.e., what thing is it that's magic for you. This is called the antecedent. The word *was* is singular, so the antecedent must be singular. *Systems*, *machines*, *devices*, and *companies* are all plural and so can't be the antecedent. The only thing left is the single situation "*how companies make* [things]". Which is want you wanted to say.

Comment: @deadrat Yes, but a reader shouldn't have to backtrack to decipher what the writer meant. OP is correct in pointing out the problem. The unnecessary inclusion of "which" made the sentence a bit confusing. I would've rewritten it as "I have [always] been fascinated by the way electrical circuits function, and how companies make devices and machines with sophisticated electronic systems has always seemed like magic to me" (or some other variation of that phrasing)

Comment: @deadrat I thought the OP's last line ("... the whole thing about electricity ...") tried to say that the magic was in the *way* electric circuits fashion. If so, it does run counter to a natural reading of the quote.

Comment: @AleksandrH Good heavens, man! Readers always have to backtrack to decipher what the writer meant. That's why it's called an *antecedent*, from the Latin, the thing going before. It's an artifact of interpreting a recursive language from linear text. What readers shouldn't have to deal with is text that makes them reconsider their parsing halfway through. The comma clearly does that, leading the reader to expect the start of an independent clause and have that expectation dashed by *which*. But that doesn't change the aptness of *was*.

Comment: @Lawrence Good point. It's not possible for the sentence to conjure the magic of just the function of electrical circuits.

Comment: @deadrat But you already encountered the antecedent before reaching "which". A well-written sentence should not require the reader to backtrack and determine what the antecedent was.

Comment: @AleksandrH I'm sorry, but I don't understand. You encounter the antecedent before you reach the relative pronoun. So at the time you encounter the antecedent, you don't know that it is an antecedent because you don't know about the relative clause yet. Then you read the relative pronoun (here, *which*). It refers to something you've read before, right? How do you know what it refers to without attaching it something you've read before?

Comment: Right, but many people have the sufficient short-term memory to recall what they read before without having to backtrack and search for the relevant antecedent once they encounter the pronoun...it's only when a sentence is poorly phrased that you find yourself confused and have to backtrack to figure out what you "missed".